# Finding an interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $\phi$ is decreasing on $I$

Tags: functions, probability-distributions

Given $0<\alpha<\beta<1$, we define a function
$$
\phi(x) = x - x \left[\frac{x^\alpha + x^\beta+1}{\alpha(x^\beta+1)+\beta(x^\alpha+1)} \right],
$$
I am trying to find additional sufficient conditions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ guaranteeing that $\phi(x)$ is decreasing on some interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}^+$. I have attempted to take the first derivative, but it is overly complicated and rather involved. Doing so, it becomes extremely hard to find values of $x$ such that $\phi'(x) < 0$.

Is it possible to reduce $\phi$ to a more familiar expression? If not, what other tool can I use to investigate the monotonicity of $\phi$?

The function $\phi$ is called the *virtual value function* for the maximum of two independent Pareto distributions with shapes $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there restrictions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: No, only that there are between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce this function to the form
\begin{equation*}
\phi(x) = x - x \Big( \frac{x^{\alpha}+x^{\beta}+1}{\alpha(x^{\beta}+1)+\beta(x^{\alpha}+1)}\Big) = \frac{\alpha x^{\beta+1} + \alpha x + \beta x^{\alpha+1} + \beta x - x^{\alpha+1} - x^{\beta+1}-x}{\alpha(x^{\beta}+1)+\beta(x^{\alpha}+1)}= \frac{(\alpha-1) x^{\beta+1}+ (\beta-1) x^{\alpha+1} +(\alpha+\beta+1) x  }{\alpha(x^{\beta}+1)+\beta(x^{\alpha}+1)}
\end{equation*}

Try using this expression, but it seems to be a completely mess though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is helpful to set $\alpha=\beta$ and then use a continuity argument (in $\beta$) to get the result for $\alpha < \beta$?

Let $f(x,\alpha,\beta) = 1 - \frac{x^\alpha + x^\beta + 1}{\alpha (x^\beta + 1) + \beta (x^\alpha +1)}$ and define $\phi (x,\alpha,\beta) = x f(x,\alpha,\beta)$.  We want $\phi_x = x f_x + f < 0$.  Now, $f(x,\alpha,\alpha) = 1 - \frac{1}{\alpha} + \frac{1}{2\alpha (x^\alpha+1)}$ and so

\begin{equation*} f_x(x,\alpha,\alpha) = -\frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{2 (x^{\alpha-1}+1)^2} \end{equation*}
and

\begin{align*} xf_x(x,\alpha,\alpha) + f(x,\alpha,\alpha) & = -\frac{x^{\alpha}}{2 (x^{\alpha}+1)^2} + 1 - \frac{2x^\alpha+1}{2\alpha (x^\alpha+1)} \\
& = \frac{-2\alpha x^{\alpha} + 2\alpha (x^\alpha+1)^2 - (2x^\alpha+1)(x^\alpha+1)}{2\alpha(x^\alpha+1)^2} \\
& = \frac{-2\alpha x^\alpha + (x^\alpha+1)\left((2\alpha -2)x^\alpha + (2\alpha - 1)\right)}{2\alpha(x^\alpha+1)^2}
\end{align*}
which is less than 0 if we take $\alpha < \frac{1}{2}$.